# Using python decorator to decorate a part of function

Tags: python, mocking, decorator

I am trying to mock our git wrapper, so that we can test it. I plan to use mockproc python library which provides the functionality to mock any process name, with a provided script. It works something like this -

```
self.scripts.append( 'process-name', returncode=0, stdout="output to process" )
with self.scripts:
        run_and_handle_result()
```

I need to add a decorator layer over this so that I can do some extra things like handle retries. What I want is something like this -

```
@mockproc('git') # tells that we are mocking git
def test_something(mock_proc):
    mock_proc.set_script("sleep (60)")
    # Run some git command
    mockproc.check_exit_signal()
```

The problem is I want my decorator to handle the `with self.scripts` part. So what I want is that the decorator runs the function, setting the process name as git, which is simple. Then run the test function, which adds the script and add `with self.script` around the git command and then resumes the function.

Is there anyway to do it ? is a decorator bad way to implement it ? This is not a cosmetic requirement. I need this because in some of my commands there is retry logic, for which I need to provide more than one script to mockproc and run multiple times.

Comment: Do you still need this? I think the code snippets are too short to ilustrate all the thing s you want done - can you put some illustrative example of: What is the fucntion supposed to do outside a testing context, and what is the expected behavior on a testing context?  I believe what you want may be achieved through contextual monkey patching, but I have to understand it better

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to override a named free variable of a function. You can use `fun.func_globals[some_name] = some_value`. E.g.

```
def x(a):
    pow2(a)

 x.func_globals['pow2'] = lambda y: y*y

 x(3) == 9
```

Comment: My problem is that the name would be different for each test so I can't override that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but I recently encountered a similar situation, where I needed wrap operations, but some were calling other, already wrapped operations, so I didn't want to recursively wrap again. I solved it with closures.

Example wrapper

```
def wrapper(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except NamedException:
            # do stuff to handle exception
            raise
     
    return decorated
```

Then I had several functions using the `@wrapper`

```
@wrapper
def some_function(stuff):
    # does some stuff
```

Then I had another function, calling one of those wrapped functions, so to prevent recursively wrapping, while still getting the wrap behavior in the new function, I made a closure.

```
def some_other_function(args):
    some_function(args)  # already wrapped

    @wrapper
    def _some_other_function()
         # do stuff with args
         return result

    return _some_other_function()
```